# Dynamically Create Controls after click of button in System.Web.UI.Page C#

Tags: c#

I need to create a new line of controls each time an end user clicks on the button that was just created. What it does is that the first time it works, then when clicked on the newly created button it does not show and that line that I created earlier disappears. Any ideas?

```
protected void btnCreateFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox txtID = new TextBox();
     txtID.Text = "";
     Panel1.Controls.Add(txtID);

     TextBox txtID = new TextBox();
     txtDesc.Text = "";
     Panel1.Controls.Add(txtDesc);

     Button btnNewLine = new Button();
     btnNewLine.ID = "btnNewLine";
     btnNewLine.Text = "New Controls";
     btnNewLine.Click = new EventHandler(btnNewLine_Click);
     Panel1.Controls.Add(btnNewLine);
}

protected void btnNewLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("This works");
}
```